# Macbook Volume Control Not Changing Volume of Bluetooth Headphones

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones, sound-volume

For some reason, when Bluetooth headphones are connected to my macbook the volume control doesn't have any effect on the headphones volume. They seem to be stuck on full volume and doesn't change when I lower the volume.

I've tried 'sudo killall coreaudiod' in the terminal but it doesn't change anything. Have restarted and re-paired the headphones but no joy. Any similar solutions haven't worked either.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this for multiple headphones on the same Mac?  Do the same headphones work correctly on other BT devices?  What kind of headphones?  Have you checked with the manufacturer?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue! I'm using a pair of Sony WI-C310 bluetooth headphones. I found out that if I open System Preferences > Sound and open the Input tab it works, but I have to keep the Settings window opened. Still haven't found an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MacOS are you on?

Can you add Sound to your menu bar and check which output is active? Is your bluetooth headset active?
[image: MacOS Sound Menu Bar Options]

Also, are you using any audio plugins or apps, like EQs? They tend to make their own audio device and route audio through there.

I recommend disconnecting every other audio device, uninstalling any audio plugins or apps, and verifying that your bluetooth headset is set as the active output device.

Comment: How can we check if there's any audio plugin installed ?? Can those all be seen at a single place in Settings ??